# How to ping an IP address using the Chrome App API

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm looking at making a simple dashboard to ping a few servers. Searching Stack Overflow I see it's not possible with Chrome "Extensions," but I see in the Chrome app store a bunch of ping apps so it appears to be possible. I just can't find any examples or documentation on it.

Can someone point me to the right place or give me some code snippets to look at?

Comment: Chrome apps can use chrome.sockets API, you can inspect any of those apps yourself in devtools or in the directory of the installed app inside your browser data profile.

Comment: I did see things like "chrome.system.network" But it doesn't seem to be what i need.

Comment: Indeed chrome.sockets is not chrome.system.network.

Comment: I did notice this, but there is only one method listed under this; getNetworkInterfaces. I do not think this would let me ping other devices?

Comment: Like I said, it's a different API not related to what I suggested in my comment.